# Using parenthesis causes decimal errors on Python and Java

Tags: java, math, python-2.7, rounding, parentheses

I was recently debugging a program that consistently returned errors just a few decimal points off. It turns out the error was on the very line I believed that I didn't need to check: `999999 * (.18 / 12)`.

I knew the parenthesis were not necessary because mathematically, the expression should evaluate to the same answer regardless of their presence, but I included them just for clarity. When I typed the statement into the Python interpreter, however, it returned `14999.98499999999`, while the correct answer should be `14999.985`. When I removed the parenthesis and typed `999999 * .18 / 12`, I got the correct answer (`14999.985`). Just to make sure it wasn't just a Python thing, I tried it with Java too, same answer.

Why is this? I understand that computers can't store fractions as exact values, so some degree of error is to be expected, but what's the difference in the way the computer evaluates those two statements?

TL;DR: `999999 * (.18 / 12)` gives me a different answer than `999999 * .18 / 12` when mathematically, they should both evaluate to `14999.985`. Why?

Comment: Read up on the limitations of representing floating point numbers on a digital computer. The results you are posting are because of this limitation, and the two numbers are *reasonably* close for most purposes.

Comment: As a result of the limitation (can't always preserve the precision of a number), different order of execution may give you different result.

Comment: The reason that are producing different results is that they are two different expressions -- with the `()` you are dividing and then multiplying, without you are multiplying and then dividing.  So, the error accumulates differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off doing a multiply before a divide. Since a divide has a lesser probable chance of being represented correctly as compared to a overflow happening during multiplication.